# RadioButton.Checked issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

So I am having a bit of issue with this piece of code for a class of mine. I know it seems rather elementary but for the life of me I am not sure why I can't get it to work.

Essentially I have 6 radio buttons and depending on which one is selected I want to assign a value to an int variable. I want to return that value to another winForm which will do something else.

but for some reason it always returns 0.

some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance..

```
    int x = 0;

    public int selectionDie1()
    {
        if (die1_1.Checked)
            x = 1;
        if (die1_2.Checked)
            x = 2;
        if (die1_3.Checked)
            x = 3;
        if (die1_4.Checked)
            x = 4;
        if (die1_5.Checked)
            x = 5;
        if (die1_6.Checked)
            x = 6;
        return x;
    }
```

I like to also add that even if I change this to a void with no return value and place a label that would display the value of x on buttonclick, it still returns a 0.

I have even tried using just one radiobutton and see if that would work, nothing at all.

when I set x = 1000; and return that it works fine, so it has to do with the radio buttons

thank you

Comment: Can you please show us how you've set up your radio buttons?

Comment: how did I set it up? II put a panel and dragged these buttons on to the panel

Comment: Code works as posted.  Issue is somewhere else.  You should probably put `int x` inside the selectionDiel function.

Comment: When(and where) is `seelctionDie1()` being called?

Comment: Do you have an event handler?

Comment: selectionDie1() gets called in another winform.

but even if i set it as a void with no return type and try to display the value of x in a label on the same winform, it still says 0.

Comment: How are you calling it from the other form?

Comment: `code` theCaller caller = new theCaller();

            int die1Value = caller.selectionDie1();

            label1.Text = die1Value.ToString();`code`

Comment: That won't work.  You created a "new" form where presumably no radio buttons have been selected yet.  You have to reference the form that is already shown.

Comment: ok but what I am saying is that even in the same winform, if I want to get the value of x and display it in a label, it still doesn't show. so if selectionDie() is void and on button_click take the value of x and place it into label, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you do the same mistake as me: do not use = x.ToString() Correct is = selectionDie1().ToString()

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are attempting to use the variable `x` in your other form. You need to use the direct result of the `selectionDie1` function.

```
public int selectionDie1()
{
    if (die1_1.Checked)
        return 1;
    else if (die1_2.Checked)
        return 2;
    ...

    else
        throw new exception("there was no item checked");
}
```

This way there is no variable to keep track of, or could be accessed from an outside location.

The other issue is that you are creating a form and then immediately checking for the selected item (if your comment is correct). You need to first create and show the form, give the user time to choose an option, and then do this function call (which might happen on a user selection, form close, button press, etc).